# AngularJs <div ng-repeat= "(key, data) in myData" > does not work in controller using $ionicPopup.alert

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object]] starting at [Object]].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$parse/syntax?p0=Object&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%5D%5D&p2=9&p3=%5Bobject" "

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$ionicPopup,$state ) {

     $scope.myData = { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2", prop3: "val3",prop4: "val4" };
                       var alertPopup =$ionicPopup.alert({

                    //templateUrl: '/templates/view.html'
                       template:
                           '<div class="row list-inset" ng-repeat= "(key, data) in '+$scope.myData+'" >'+
                         '<div class="col font_type2" >{{key}}</div>'+
                         '<div class="col font_type2" >{{data}}</div>'+
                         '</div>'

                      });
});
```

Comment: In template use $compile, as template:$compile("<content>"), and in $scope.myData use scape, "JSON.stringify($scope.myData)"

Comment: Hi Emir, i am using JSON.stringify($scope.myData) in ng-repeat tag but not work.

Comment: Your problem is concat the $scope.myData(Object) with String. When this ocurred Js interpret $scope.MyData as $scope.MyData.toString(), This returned "Object". For fix serializable $scope.MyData, after concat with String

Comment: For serializable use:  angular.element($scope.myData).serialize();

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is concat the $scope.myData(Object) with String. When this ocurred Js interpret $scope.MyData as $scope.MyData.toString(), This returned "Object". For fix serializable $scope.MyData, after concat with String.

For serializable use: angular.element($scope.myData).serialize();

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$ionicPopup,$state ) {
    $scope.myData = { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2", prop3: "val3",prop4: "val4" };
    var alertPopup =$ionicPopup.alert({
        //templateUrl: '/templates/view.html'
        template:
        '<div class="row list-inset" ng-repeat= "(key, data) in '+angular.element($scope.myData).serialize()+'" >'+
        '<div class="col font_type2" >{{key}}</div>'+
        '<div class="col font_type2" >{{data}}</div>'+
        '</div>'
    });
});
```

Comment: ng-repeat is not working here "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 10 of the expression [[[object Object]]] starting at [Object]]].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$parse/syntax?p0=Object&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%5D%5D&p2=10&p3=%5B%5Bobject" "<!-- ngRepeat: (key, data) in [[object Object]] -->" "bject%5D%5D&p4=Object%5D%5D

Comment: serialize is not a method of angularJs. angular provide serializeToString().

Comment: serialize is method jquery. Try print console.log(angular.element($scope.myData).serialize())

Comment: I am not using JQuery. only used in Ionic and angularJS.so this situation serialize is not work. bt I am get the answer, why my ng-repeat was not work? bcz myData's value is empty in ionicPopup so define $ionicPopup.alert in scope: $scope=scope;

Comment: Print this in console: '<div class="row list-inset" ng-repeat= "(key, data) in '+angular.element($scope.myData).serialize()+'" >'+
        '<div class="col font_type2" >{{key}}</div>'+
        '<div class="col font_type2" >{{data}}</div>'+
        '</div>'

Comment: Thank you Emir for given knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

> $scope so they can assign it as the scope property in the popup show
>   options and scope of the popup for the data-binding.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$ionicPopup,$state ) {

     $scope.myData = { prop1: "val1", prop2: "val2", prop3: "val3",prop4: "val4" };
                       var alertPopup =$ionicPopup.alert({

                       scope: $scope,       // define the scope is here.

                       //templateUrl: '/templates/view.html'
                       template:
                           '<div class="row list-inset" ng-repeat= "(key, data) in '+$scope.myData+'" >'+
                         '<div class="col font_type2" >{{key}}</div>'+
                         '<div class="col font_type2" >{{data}}</div>'+
                         '</div>'

                      });
});
```